# I'm trying to make same page of php shows up depends of the ID taken from DB

Tags: php

Well what i'm trying to do , let's say i got page https://test.com/public

I want to make this page shows Data from DB and make the link like this

https://test.com/public=1 (shows data of ID 1 (row1))
https://test.com/public=2 (shows data of ID 2 (row2))
I'm tottality lost i know how to select from DB but idk what to do to make like what i was saying

Answer (score 0):

get page URL, extract id from it and use that id to query database

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; //or $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'];
```

extract id from URL

```
$id = explode('=', $url);
$id = (int) $id[1];
```

now use $id in your SQL query

simpler method would be PHP $_GET to get id from URL (test.com/?public=1) and pass it to SQL query

```
$public = $_GET['public'];

$query = "SELECT * from table where id = $public";
```

Also do some input validation and use prepared statements to avoid SQL Injection, for more information search php.net and Google